# How to resolve this onSuccesListener error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So in the following on Success Listener code:

```
database.collection("users")
            .add(users)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    
                }
            })
```

I am getting the error:

> 'addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>)'

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you need to read a single document or multiple documents?

Comment: I need to check if the while registering as a user does the user currently exists or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
        |
        --- $uid (document)
             |
             --- // user fields.
```

To check if a particular users already exists, please use the following lines of cde:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);
    uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d("TAG", "User already exists.");   
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "User doesn't exist.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly! This will help you @Nimish

Comment: Thank you this did help

Answer (score 0):

It's as the stacktrace implies, you're using the wrong parameter in the listener. You need to use `OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>` or any superclass of `DocumentReference`.

### EDIT:

Reference from Firebase : [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

You need to use `DocumentReference`:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Tokyo");
data.put("country", "Japan");

db.collection("cities")
        .add(data)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
            }
        });
```

Use the resulting id to get the document again.

Comment: But if i want to use document snapshot to check existing user how to do it?

Comment: Can you give the full line where you are calling `addOnSuccessListener`?

Comment: done. Please Check

Comment: why dont you use lambda?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal lambda won't solve the problem in this case, there was a parameter mismatch. Eventually, it'll boil down to non-existent methods of the parameter class. Lambda will of course help afterwards

Comment: Hi @NimishGodbole, i am currently busy. I will write the answer later.